# Generics Deriving

Tags: c#, oop

I have situation like following:

```
public interface I {}
public class D1 : I {}
public class D2 : I {}

public class A
{
    public List<D1> Collection {get;set;}
    //Other Members
}
public class B
{
    public List<D2> Collection {get;set;}
    //Other Members
}
```

So, both A and B have List with elements derived from I.

How can I define base class for A and B?

P.S. I Tried to generalize base class:

```
class Base<T> where T : I
{
   List<T> Collection {get;set;}
}
A:Base<D1>{..}; B:Base<D2> {..}
```

But it gives me nothing (or I only think so) : 
 I can't do so:

`Base<I> b;
   b= new A();
   b= new B();`

because it is impossible to cast from `List<I>` to `List<D1>`

Thanks

Comment: What is the relationship between A and List<T>? is it an A 'is-a' List<T> relationship or is it an A 'has-a' List<T> relationship? What about B? From the answers we can proceed more clearly.

Comment: that's a covariance/contravariance problem. You can fix it with an `in` or `out` keyword in your list definition.

Comment: Thanx Stephane, can you сlarify your answer a bit? Maybe some useful links about covariance/contravariance, because I face this problem for not the first time

Comment: You should read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx and spend some time understanding covariance and contravariance.

Your statement that this is impossible because you can't cast from List<I> to List<D1> isn't the whole story. While that is impossible, because List<T> isn't covariant, you can remove the List<T> entirely from your base class and still see a compiler error, because Base<T> itself is not covariant. It also can't be, as C# doesn't allow for invariant classes; co/contravariance can only be defined on interfaces and delegates.

Comment: That should read C# ONLY allows for invariant generic classes.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about it, it does make sense.

Consider this:

```
Base<I> b = new B();
b.List.Add(new D1);
```

Theoretically, that would be valid code. `Base<I>.List` is a `List<I>`. `D1` inherits from `I`. But we know that List is really `List<D2>` (as defined in `B`). Therefore our call to Add can't possibly work.

If you don't need to actually add items to the collection, you can switch some things around to make it work:

```
public interface IBase<out T> where T : I
{
    IEnumerable<T> Collection { get; }
}

public class A : IBase<D1>
{
    IEnumerable<D1> Collection { get; private set; }

    public A(IEnumerable<D1> list)
    {
        Collection = list;
    }
}

public class B : IBase<D2>
{
    IEnumerable<D2> Collection { get; private set; }

    public B(IEnumerable<D2> list)
    {
        Collection = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: @PrestonGuillot - Updated with an example that works. Actually checked this one in VS2012.